# Grails 2.5.5 controller unit test cannot cast object error

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I've been trying to set up a unit test for a controller. However, any attempt to access the `controller` property causes the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'class au.org.ala.collectory.ContactController' with class 'java.lang.Class' to class 'au.org.ala.collectory.ContactController'
```

Here's the code that I've been using:

```
package au.org.ala.collectory

import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(ContactController)
@Mock([Contact, CollectoryAuthService])
class ContactControllerTests extends Specification {
    def contact

    def setup() {
        contact = new Contact(
            title: "Dr",
            firstName: "Lemmy",
            lastName: "Caution",
            phone: "0262465909",
            mobile: "0419468551",
            email: "lemmy.caution@csiro.au",
            notes: "to be treated with exaggerated respect",
            publish: true,
            userLastModified: 'test')
     }


    def testList() {
        when:
        contact.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
        request.contentType = JSON_CONTENT_TYPE
        controller.list()
        then:
        model.contactInstanceList.size() == 1
        model.contactInstanceList[0].title == 'Dr'
    }
}
```

I've tried various combinations of code placement and mocking, all to no avail. Any explanation as to why I would be getting this error would be most appreciated.

Comment: start with a clean, do you have this issue with other controller tests?

Comment: I've done a clean and rebuilt and re-tested. It's only this specific controller test; other tests are fine. Creating it from scratch produces the same behaviour. Removing the contact and just having a test that basically does controller.list() still produces the same behaviour.

Comment: An absolutely minimal test also does the same thing:

    package au.org.ala.collectory
    
    import grails.test.mixin.TestFor import spock.lang.Specification

    @TestFor(ContactController)
    class XTests extends Specification {
        void testIndex() {
            when:
            controller.index()
            then:
            model != null
        }
    }

Comment: Is controller in correct place? Maybe strip everything out of controller apart from `def index(){}` with corresponding test as per your last comment & run test

Comment: The controller is in the correct place. It all actually works in real life, just not in the test cases.

Stripping everything out has proved interesting. The offending bit of code in the controller is this:

    def name = {
        def contactInstance = Contact.get(params.id)
        if (!contactInstance) {
            render "contact not found"
        }
        else {
            render contactInstance.buildName()
        }
    }

If I delete this, everything works. I imagine that `name` has some special meaning in the test framework.

Comment: Changing the code from a closure to a method makes the problem go away. Thanks @MikeW for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by a `def name = {` closure in the controller. This seems to interfere with the AST transformation taking place. Changing the closure to a method, ie `def name() {` allows the tests to run.

Comment: Conversely, a `def save() {` method seems to be silently ignored.